# Concatenate tuples in empty dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, error-handling, tuples

```
errors = {}

#errorexample
errors['id'] += ('error1',)
errors['id'] += ('error2',)

#works but ugly
errors['id'] = ('error1',)
errors['id'] += ('error2',)
```

If 'error1' is not present it will fail. Do I really have to extend dict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) instead of a plain `dict` -- this kind of convenience, after all, is exactly what the default-dict type was introduced for:

```
>>> import collections
>>> errors = collections.defaultdict(tuple)
>>> errors['id'] += ('error1',)
>>> errors['id'] += ('error2',)
>>> errors['id']
('error1', 'error2')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import collections
errors = collections.defaultdict(tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> errors = defaultdict (tuple)
>>> errors['id'] += ('blargh',)
>>> errors['id']
('blargh',)
```